# как выводить текст "да" если запущен процесс "а.ехе" в противном случае выводить "нет" (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

для определения процесса использую

```
import psutils
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    name = proc.name()
    if name == "rufus-4.4p.exe":
        print('yes')
        pass
```

этот код выводит да если процесс запущен

но нужно чтобы если процесс не запущен надо выводить нет
добавление

```
    else:
        print('нет')
        pass  

или  

    if name != "rufus-4.4p.exe":
        print('no')
        pass
```

и подобное не помогает. Если процесс запущен, то в консоли очень много раз выводит "нет" и один раз "да" чего быть в моем случае не должно быть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрел документацию, да просто if/else работать не будет.

Вот как то так, на Code.exe проверил:

```
import psutil

def check_process():
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        try:
            if proc.name() == 'Code.exe':
                return "Да"
        except (psutil.NoSuchProcess, psutil.AccessDenied):
            return "Что-то пошло не так..."
    return "Нет"

print(check_process())
```

Answer (score 1):

Самый легкий способ:

```
import psutils
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    name = proc.name()
    if name == "rufus-4.4p.exe":
        print ('yes')
        found = True
        break
    else:
        found = False
if found == False:
    print('no')
```

Comment: увы это не совсем работает, если программа закрыта то пишет no, если открыта то пишет yes и на след строке no

Comment: @oleg сейчас немного изменю

Comment: странно но все равно при запущенной программе пишет yes и no

Comment: @oleg теперь точно пофиксил и на практике проверил

Comment: точно теперь все нормально